# Subscribe one one Item and read multiple other ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

i try to create a opc-ua-client with the "node-opcua"-npm package (NodeJs) to do the following thing:
I wan`t to subscribe to one item and every time this value changed i want to do a simple read on about 200 other variables to save it in a file or a database.

The Background is that my Subscription-Item is a Counter that counts + 1 when a new dataset is availible. Then i wan`t so save a couple of other sensor values to make some analyses afterwords.

What is the best way to do that?
I don´t really get it run by myself.

Please support

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.